# Universal Analytics - Goal Conversion Problem

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a problem with my conversions on google analytics. I saw that there is no conversion since a specific date. My goals were set according to the category, action, label, and value structure from GTM.

I checked the GTM tag, it is configured correctly and triggered properly when I get a preview. I checked also the goal settings on google analytics, it seems okay. There were conversions in the past but for a few weeks, there are not been any. Why it could happen? Do you have any ideas?

[Datalayer - 1st goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEmru.png)

[GTM Tag - 1st goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLP6T.png)

[UA - 1st goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ynYD.png)

[Datalayer - 2nd goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMNV1.png)

[GTM Tag - 2nd goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXfWq.png)

[UA - 2nd goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hlBz.png)

Comment: add screenshot of configuration and dataLayer, pls

Comment: I think I put it in the wrong format but once you copy and paste the links you will have the screenshots. @MichelePisani

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `{{Page Path}}` as value of a field in Google Analytics Goal settings because it is a variable of GTM.

Google Analytics receives only the true value of the page path, so if you set `label` equal to `{{Page Path}}` you will have **no Goal** because no URL is equal to string `{{Page Path}}` but for example to `/my-path/page/`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated {{Page Path}} with the outcomes but it didn't solve the problem. I think there is something different.

Comment: Try to not set the label